# Twilio modify sms message before forwarding using TWIML

Tags: twilio

Trying to modify a SMS message (adding  a name based on the from phone number) before forwarding the message to a phone using TWIML. The phone no list is small so I will use a switch statement I am guessing in a function. I am not sure how can I wire this together w/o my own server and just using Twilio hosted stuff (TWIML, function, ?)?

Comment: maybe better asking on their support?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can absolutely modify the message before forwarding it on.

If you're looking to do so without using your own server, then [Twilio Functions](https://www.twilio.com/functions) is your best bet. Twilio Functions gives you access to a Node.js environment in which you can write functions that respond to webhooks.

To forward a message to a number but add a name based on the incoming number, you can do something like this in a function:

```
contacts = {
  "number": "name"
}

exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
  const name = contacts[event.From];
  if (typeof name !== 'undefined') {
    const message = `${name} said: ${event.Body}`;
    const response = new Twilio.twiml.MessagingResponse();
    response.Message({ to: YOUR_NUMBER, from: YOUR_TWILIO_NUMBER }, message);
    callback(null, response);
  } else {
    // handle not having a name in the contacts
  }
}
```

Check out this [quick start on using Twilio Functions](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/runtime/programmable-voice#function-templates) for more detail.

Comment: Introducing Twilio Functions (at Signal 2017) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PKodXk6L5Eo